# View Group не отображает дочерние view на маленьком экране

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, view, viewgroup

Реализовал собственный FlexBoxLayout, работает адекватно, но как только высота устройства становится маленькой, дочерние элементы ViewGroup перестают отрисовываться.

Код flexBoxLayout

```
class EmojiReactionFlexBoxLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : ViewGroup(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var spaceBetweenHorizontal = 0f
        set(value) {
            field = value
            requestLayout()
        }
    private var spaceBetweenVertical = 0f
        set(value) {
            field = value
            requestLayout()
        }

    init {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.EmojiReactionFlexBoxLayout,
            defStyleAttr,
            defStyleRes
        )
        spaceBetweenHorizontal =
            typedArray.getDimension(
                R.styleable.EmojiReactionFlexBoxLayout_erfb_space_between_horizontal,
                0F
            )
        spaceBetweenVertical =
            typedArray.getDimension(
                R.styleable.EmojiReactionFlexBoxLayout_erfb_space_between_vertical,
                0F
            )
        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        var totalWidth = 0
        var totalHeight = 0
        val widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            measureChildWithMargins(child, widthMeasureSpec, 0, heightMeasureSpec, totalWidth)
            totalHeight = maxOf(totalHeight, child.measuredHeight)
            totalWidth += child.measuredWidth + spaceBetweenHorizontal.toInt()
        }
        val maxChildHeight: Int = totalHeight
        var countStrings: Int = ceil(totalWidth.toFloat() / widthSize.toFloat()).toInt()
        while (countStrings > 1) {
            countStrings--
            totalHeight += maxChildHeight + spaceBetweenVertical.toInt()
        }
        val resultWidth = resolveSize(totalWidth, widthMeasureSpec)
        val resultHeight = resolveSize(totalHeight, heightMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(resultWidth, resultHeight)
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        var currentRight = 0
        var currentTop = 0
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            if (currentRight + child.measuredWidth > measuredWidth) {
                currentTop += child.measuredHeight + spaceBetweenVertical.toInt()
                currentRight = 0
            }
            child.layout(
                currentRight,
                currentTop,
                currentRight + child.measuredWidth,
                currentTop + child.measuredHeight
            )
            currentRight = child.right + spaceBetweenHorizontal.toInt()
        }
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(attrs: AttributeSet?): LayoutParams {
        return MarginLayoutParams(context, attrs)
    }

    override fun checkLayoutParams(p: LayoutParams): Boolean {
        return p is MarginLayoutParams
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(p: LayoutParams): LayoutParams {
        return MarginLayoutParams(p)
    }
}
```

Код child элемента

```
open class EmojiReactionButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0
    ) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        private var countReactions = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                requestLayout()
            }
    
        private var emoji = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                requestLayout()
            }
    
        private val textPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
            textSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.simple_text)
            textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
            color = Color.RED
        }
        private val viewRect = Rect()
        private val textCoordinate = PointF()
    
        private val tempFontMetrics = Paint.FontMetrics()
    
        init {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.EmojiReactionButton,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes
            )
            countReactions =
                typedArray.getString(R.styleable.EmojiReactionButton_erb_count_reactions).orEmpty()
            emoji =
                typedArray.getString(R.styleable.EmojiReactionButton_erb_emoji).orEmpty()
            textPaint.color =
                typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.EmojiReactionButton_erb_color, Color.WHITE)
    
            textPaint.textSize = typedArray.getDimension(
                R.styleable.EmojiReactionButton_erb_text_size,
                resources.getDimension(R.dimen.simple_text)
            )
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    
        override fun setOnClickListener(l: OnClickListener?) {
            super.setOnClickListener(l)
            isSelected = !isSelected
            if (!isSelected) {
                setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            } else {
                setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
            textPaint.getTextBounds(
                "$countReactions $emoji",
                0,
                "$countReactions $emoji".length,
                viewRect
            )
    
            val totalHeight = viewRect.height() + paddingTop + paddingBottom
            val totalWidth = viewRect.width() + paddingRight + paddingLeft
    
            val resultWidth = resolveSize(totalWidth, widthMeasureSpec)
            val resultHeight = resolveSize(totalHeight, heightMeasureSpec)
    
            setMeasuredDimension(resultWidth, resultHeight)
        }
    
        override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
            textPaint.getFontMetrics(tempFontMetrics)
    
            textCoordinate.x = w / 2f
            textCoordinate.y = h / 2f + viewRect.height() / 2 - tempFontMetrics.descent
        }
    
        override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
            val drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + EXTRA_SUPPORTED_DRAWABLE_STATE.size)
            if (isSelected) {
                mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, EXTRA_SUPPORTED_DRAWABLE_STATE)
            }
            return drawableState
        }
    
        fun setTextColor(color: Int) {
            textPaint.color = color
            invalidate()
        }
    
        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
            canvas.drawText("$emoji $countReactions", textCoordinate.x, textCoordinate.y, textPaint)
        }
    
        companion object {
            private val EXTRA_SUPPORTED_DRAWABLE_STATE = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected)
        }
    
    }
```

[image: Высота экрана большая]

[image: Высота экрана маленькая]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в методе `onMeasure` я использовал `measureChildWithMargins`, а не `measureChild`.